# How can I Insert data in database on link click event?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to insert a value in database when visitor click on a link.

For example:

1. Visitor comes on http://www.website.com/lp.php?id=broker
2. When he clicks on "Register now" I want to add the id value "broker" & the current time into database.

I need the javascript code to do that. I already tried all kind of scripts and I decided to ask here.

Comment: JavaScript runs in the browser; the action you want needs to take place on a server. This isn't easily answered, I'd read up on "backend web development"

Comment: You have a "PHP' tag on this question.  Have you tried PHP to do this?

Comment: The only way I found to do that was to POST the id value and link the button to a 3 seconds redirect page (because the link goes to an external page) to run the input data script.
But I don't like this way because of that 3 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with jQuery Ajax and PHP or using HTML POST form.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

With jQuery:

```
$("#register_now_button_id").click(function(){  
    //AJAX CALL HERE
});
```